# How would you find a graph G, such that both it and its complement would have cut vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I am assuming that the instructor is wanting us also to assume that graph G one has a cut vertex, then the compliment  G' would have a different vertex as a cut vertex.

Answer (score 1):

The graph $P_4$ (the path with four vertices) is isomorphic to its complement and clearly has a cut vertex.

Answer (score 1):

This construction generalizes Jorge Fernández Hidalgo's [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2116708/91818).

Take a disconnected graph $G \cup H$ with $\geq 3$ vertices and no edges between $G$ and $H$.  Add a vertex $v$, and connect it to all vertices in $G \cup H$ except one, $u$ say.  By definition $v$ is a cut vertex of this graph.

An example is show below:

[image]

And its complement is:

[image]

In the complement, $v$ has the unique neighbor $u$, which has a neighbor other than $v$ (since $G \cup H$ is disconnected), highlighted in orange above.  Thus $u$ is a cut vertex in the complement.